# VS Unit Tests callback action not executing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have below mocked objects and I am mocking up IDataReader's read call as below:

```
var read = true;
Mock<IDataReader> dataReader = new Mock<IDataReader>();
dataReader.Setup(rd => rd.Read()).Returns(read).Callback(() => 
    {
        read = false;
    });
```

Now I have below piece of code in which I am using above objects:

```
while (iDataReader.Read())
{
    // ...
}
```

Problem here is, its going in infinite loop. But as I set `read = false` in call back, IDataReader.Read() should return true only first time and false afterwards but it is returning true all the time.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `Returns`, it's using the value of the variable at the time you called it.  So `Read` will always return `true`, regardless of what you do to the `read` variable afterwards.

What you're looking to do is setup a sequence, and Moq has support for this:

```
dataReader.SetupSequence(rd => rd.Read()).Returns(true).Returns(false);
```